# “cannot execute binary file: Exec format error” cloudfoundry cf-cli

Tags: raspbian, arm

I am installing cloud foundry command line in Raspberry P2 running raspbian Jessie, I have tried ways using the Installer and the binary Installation, I have tried to force the architecture amrhf. The result I get when running the cf command on the terminal is "/usr/bin/cf: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error" I have tried to change the mode with this command "chmod +x /usr/bin/cf" the error is still there.

Comment: Looking at the cloud foundry [releases page](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/releases), it appears that all of the available downloads target x86 architecture.

Comment: `file /usr/bin/cf` should settle that one way or the other.

Comment: @Masa, it is really interesting to have an arm-incompatible binary under /usr/bin. How did you place it in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Billp3rd says, it seems that the binary (`/usr/bin/cf`) is not compiled for ARM architecture.

You need to compile it from source. To do so:

**Install `go` on your raspi, because `cf` is developed in `go`**

Do not use `apt-get install golang`. If it has been installed from repo, remove it by `apt-get remove golang; apt-get autoremove`.

`The version 1.3.1` in the repo **has known bugs**. Instead download arm distribution of `the latest version` which is 1.7.1 for now.

```
   root@mypi:~# cd /opt
   root@mypi:/opt# wget https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.7.1.linux-armv6l.tar.gz
   root@mypi:/opt# tar xvf go1.7.1.linux-armv6l.tar.gz 
   root@mypi:/opt# cd ~
```

The archive is extracted to `/opt/go`.

**Create a folder for `GOPATH`.** I choose `/root/mygopath`.

```
root@mypi:~# mkdir /root/mygopath
```

**Set variables required for `go`**

```
root@mypi:~# export GOROOT=/opt/go
root@mypi:~# export GOPATH=/root/mygopath
```

**Download and build `cf-cli`**. This process takes some time.

```
root@mypi:~# /opt/go/bin/go get code.cloudfoundry.org/cli
```

In normal circumtances, the `cli` binary should be created under `/root/mygopath/bin/`.

**Copy or move `cli` binary compiled for ARM.** I prefer to put it under `/opt/cf/`.

```
root@mypi:~# mkdir /opt/cf
root@mypi:~# cp /root/mygopath/bin/cli /opt/cf/
```

Here is output of `cli` command on ARM.

```
root@mypi:~# /opt/cf/cli 
/opt/cf/cli version BUILT_FROM_SOURCE-BUILT_AT_UNKNOWN_TIME, Cloud Foundry command line tool
Usage: /opt/cf/cli [global options] command [arguments...] [command options]

Before getting started:
  config    login,l      target,t
  help,h    logout,lo    

Application lifecycle:
  apps,a        logs      set-env,se
  push,p        ssh       create-app-manifest
  start,st      app       
  stop,sp       env,e     
  restart,rs    scale     
  restage,rg    events
```

Comment: Thanks @vaha, I have tried to follow your instructions, but now once I run this command "./bin/build"  then I get this Generating Binary...
main.go:10:2:

Comment: Generating Binary...
main.go:10:2: cannot find package "code.cloudfoundry.org/cli/cf/cmd" in any of:
 /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/code.cloudfoundry.org/cli/cf/cmd (from $GOROOT)
 /usr/local/sbin/src/code.cloudfoundry.org/cli/cf/cmd (from $GOPATH)
 /usr/local/bin/src/code.cloudfoundry.org/cli/cf/cmd
 /usr/sbin/src/code.cloudfoundry.org/cli/cf/cmd
 /usr/bin/src/code.cloudfoundry.org/cli/cf/cmd
 /sbin/src/code.cloudfoundry.org/cli/cf/cmd
 /bin/src/code.cloudfoundry.org/cli/cf/cmd
 /usr/local/games/src/code.cloudfoundry.org/cli/cf/cmd
 /usr/games/src/code.cloudfoundry.org/cli/cf/cmd

Comment: Those errors are caused by wrong GOPATH value. You should set GOPATH to where you cloned the source in. At the current step, you should look for GO specific solutions in GO related sites from GO experts =).

Comment: I think I found how to compile. I will test when I access to my raspberry.

Comment: Thanks @vaha. I am trying but still the same:(

Comment: Answer is updated. It explains how to make `cf-cli` work on ARM. It is ready to be upvoted and set as the accepted answer =)